# Programmatic GKMatchmaker Not Finding Other Players

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit, gkmatchmaker

I've been struggling for awhile trying to implement my own GKMatchmaker interface (no GKMatchmakerViewController). I have a separate GameKitHelper class as written in the Ray Wenderlich tutorial that implements the GKMatchDelegate and GKLocalPlayerListener. When I used the GKMatchmakerViewController, I had invites and random matchmaking working flawlessly. However, I tried to switch to my own view controller that fired, with the click of a button, a "findMatchWithminPlayers(....)" as shown below that created a shared GKMatchmaker to perform "findMatchForRequest(... withCompletionHandler:...)". I have a couple println()s testing for certain values but every time the match.expectedPlayerCount never reaches 0, just stays at 1. This means the "if matchStarted == false and match.expectedPlayersCount == 0" is never satisfied and the lookupPlayers() method never called/match can't be started. Here's the first method called by clicking the button:

```
func findMatchWithDetails(minPlayers: Int, maxPlayers: Int, playerGroup: Int, delegate: GameKitHelperDelegate) {

    if enableGameCenter == false {
        println("dont want to be in here")
        return
    }

    matchStarted = false
    gkMatch = nil
    gkDelegate = delegate

    var request = GKMatchRequest()
    request.minPlayers = 2
    request.maxPlayers = 2
    request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2
    request.playerGroup = 0

    println(request)

    let matchMaker = GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker()
    println(matchMaker)

    matchMaker.findMatchForRequest(request, withCompletionHandler: { (match: GKMatch!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println("matchmaking canceled")
            return
        }

        self.gkMatch = match
        self.gkMatch?.delegate = self
        println(match.expectedPlayerCount)
        println(match)
        if self.matchStarted == false && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0 {
            println("in here")
            self.lookupPlayers()
            matchMaker.finishMatchmakingForMatch(self.gkMatch!)
        }
    })
}
```

And here's the GKMatchDelegate's player state change method that should be called when a player connects:

```
func match(match: GKMatch, playerID: String, didChangeState state: GKPlayerConnectionState) {
    if gkMatch != match {
        println("definitely dont want to be in here")
        return
    }

    println("there was a state change")

    switch(state) {
    case GKPlayerConnectionState.StateConnected:

        if matchStarted == false && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0 {
            println("in connected")
            self.lookupPlayers()
        }
        break
    case GKPlayerConnectionState.StateDisconnected:
        println("maybe in disconnected")
        matchStarted = false
        gkDelegate?.matchEnded()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Let me know if you can find the problem please I would greatly appreciate it. There's two possibilities I am currently playing with: I need somewhere to create a match only on one match with the other device joining that match using a couple different methods... Or I need to implement the addPlayersToMatch(...) and finishedMatchmaking(...) methods somewhere. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: I am testing on 2 different iPhone 5s and also trying on iPhone 5 to simulator

Comment: You are using sandbox accounts right?

Comment: Ya, but using sandbox accounts was fine with the GKMatchmakerViewController setup so I think it is something else wacky.

Comment: @TimCron Did you ever solve this?